# How to change uibutton image after selected in xib file

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have a uibutton in my XIB i want to change its image after its been selected

I have change the  **state config to (highlighted)** and **background -image to = "image i want to change".**

But its not working . xcode version = 4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the **state config** for `selected` not `highlighted`

Comment: Hi i did it . but it hasn't changed

Comment: I just tested this in a project I have and it works, make sure you're setting the button's state to `selected`.  So if you want it to look selected when you press the button, in the onPress action tied to the button set `myButton.selected = YES`.